# I have seen a video of testing on multiple devices simultaneously using Yeoman. How does this work? Is there any documentation?

Tags: testing, cross-browser, device, yeoman

In the video there were several devices all updating simultaneously with each save of the file being edited. I assume this is using a `grunt server` command.

This seems the perfect setup for testing - I didn't see a TV but that would be useful too, and easy enough.

Is there any documentation for this, or an answer if anyone knows? I will return and post if I find anything.

Thanks.
Paul